# bloc no adding data inside firebase verifyPhoneNumber function

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, bloc

i want to pass false bool when firebase send otp ,but bloc is not updating its value in stremBuilder please help
my code is as below

```
 Future phoneAuthontication(
    context,
    phoneNumber,
  ) async {
    try {
      auth.userChanges();
      await auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
          phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
          verificationCompleted: (_) {},
          verificationFailed: (e) {
            errorSnackBar(context, e.toString());
          },
          codeSent: (String verificationId, int? token) {
            // MyPopUps().otpPopUp(context, verificationId, phoneNumber, token);

            _myBloc.loadingSynk.add(false);
           
          },
          timeout: const Duration(seconds: 20),
          codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (e) {
            errorSnackBar(context, 'Timeout,please try again');
          });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```